# Massive/automatic VHDL refactoring

Tags: windows, software-development, c, refactoring, lint

Currently I'm linting our codebase. Some coding rules where defined at the beginning of the project, unfortunately not very much of them were used ;\

Is there an automatic way to refactor the code?
For example ports that should be written in capital letters.

`port_name` → `PORT_NAME`

I would rather use a more "intelligent" way like the refactoring for C/C++ in Eclipse which understands the code and does not only find and replace.

I'm using Sigasi, which has such a feature, but this feature does not scale very well, I have to chose each port by hand to start a refactor action.
For thousands of ports this is a problem.

Is there a tool out there that runs on Windows 7 which is capable of something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The Unix command line tools were made for this sort of thing. You don't necessarily need full syntax parsing if regexes can be made to fit your specific needs. If you can't get what you need using in-editor replacement as @Paebbels suggested then consider using Gnu sed. It is easiest to get on Windows by installing Cygwin or you can install one of the Msys ports.

Gnu sed has an extension that will uppercase a matched pattern and another that will in-place edit a file.

After matching the start of a port this script loops until no substitutions are made which indicates the end of the port:

```
# Capitalize formals in a port interface list
sed -i -e "/port *(/ {s/[^(;:]*:/\U&/g;: pdef;n;s/[^;:]*:/\U&/g;t pdef}" *.vhdl
```

This doesn't handle blank or comment lines in the port but additional match rules can be inserted to force a no-change substitution on them so that the loop doesn't terminate early.

If you want to capitalize the formals in an association list use the following:

```
sed -i -e "s/[[:alnum:]_]* *=>/\U&/g" *.vhdl
```

This will work for the most common case where the formal isn't wrapped in a function call.

If you need to capitalize all other places where these port names are used then you can produce a script that dumps out all the port formals as a new sed script. Then use that generated script to capitalize any word that matches.

```
sed -n -e "/port *(/ {s/[^(;:]*:/\U&/gp;: pdef;n;s/[^;:]*:/\U&/gp;t pdef}" foo.vhdl | \
sed -n -e "s/\([(,;]\)/\1\n/gp" | \
sed -n -e "s/ *\([[:alnum:]_]*\) *[:,].*/\1/p" | \
sed -e "s%\(.*\)%s/\1/\U\1\L/gi%" > foo_uc.sed

sed -i -f foo_uc.sed foo.vhdl
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a smart editor, which can open multiple files at once and apply regular expressions?

This would at least work for your lowercase to uppercase example. Maybe you can apply many refactorings with this method and reduce the so needed hand made 'Sigasi refactorings' to a acceptable minimum.

*Notepad++* can apply regexp replace rules on multiple files (apply to all open files).

*PowerShell* can be used to perform Linux like `cat | sed` operations:

```
Get-ChildItem . *.vhd -Recurse `
  | ForEach {Get-Content $_ -Encoding ASCII `
    | ForEach {$_ -replace "exit","----"} `
    | Out-File "$($_).new" -Encoding ASCII `
    }
```

This expression replaces every `exit` by `----` in all `*.vhd` files below the current directory. I renamed all output files to `*.vhd.new`

Comment: What's to prevent this from renaming something that is NOT a port name? If it will make that mistake, why is this a valid answer?

Comment: It's a rexexp and it's as powerful as you wish it to be. Your solution needs a whole language grammar for a simple replace.

Comment: Regexes are not as powerful as you want them to be.  You did not answer the question.  You could answer it by writing a regex that didn't make the mistake.  I don't think you can.

Comment: As you can read below, Kevin posted a regexp to do this job! Modern regexps are not restricted to regular grammar! More over your suggested solution also uses a grammar that is based on regexp to parse tokens!

Comment: I believe you need to know which symbols are defined in which scopes to solve this problem right.  I believe you have to parse the VHDL text to determine scopes and names-in-scopes.   To the extent that your "modern regular expression" can "fully parse" the VHDL *and* do the name resolution, you might be right.  But, if your modern RE can fully parse the VHDL, then your answer is essentially "use a parser"; to extent it cannot, it cannot.  Assuming your modern VHDL fully parses, I fail to see how it handles the scoping problem.

Comment: You are missing the question and my answer: The OP asked for a tool to apply some coding styles not to refactor it. His choise of doing so was to use refactoring, which is very time intensive with his tool of choise (it uses refactoring). My suggestion was to reduce the refactorings by using simple search&replace rules so he has to apply less refactorings.

Comment: It seems *you* are missing the question.  Op said: "I would rather use a more *intelligent* way like the refactoring for C/C++ in eclipse which *understands* the code and does not only find and replace."  (Your response: "using simple search and replace" seems to violate that directly).   Regexes don't understand the code.  You have not made the case that they can even do the simple rename he requested.

Comment: It's not needed to fully parse VHDL or to calculate scopes to apply some coding style rules. More over there is no complete, latest and tool readable VHDL grammar on the internet, so the OP has to write his own grammar. This would cause more work than simply appling refactorings or writing some regexp rules. If VHDL code transformation is so easy there would be better VHDL <-> Verilog translaters.

Comment: Rexexp (to be precise PCRE - perl compatible regular expressions) are expressions to build NFAs. The regular grammar is extended by lookforward, lookbehind assertions and it's possible to access saved data like a stack automata. It acutally parses context sensitive languages.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand your reference to "rexexp"; not surprising since you didn't mention in you answer or define until the last comment.  I agree that PCRE are more powerful than regexps.  But an NFA is *not* capable of processing a context-free language.  You may argue that PCREs can process *some* context sensitive languages; sure, if it can make decisions on (some) things in its past ("left context").   That that is different than it can handle all context sensitie langauges either in a theoretical or practical way, let alone handle the specific context senstive langauge called "VHDL".

Comment: I assert you need name and type resolution to do renames (a specific requirement of OP), or your tool will sometimes rename an identifier incorrectly because it doesn't understand the scoping rules.  Your answer claimed "regexp" was enough. In comments you have fallen back to "rexexps", which are more powerful. The key question is, "are they powerful enough" (to justify your answer)?  The only reasonable evidence for this is an actual coded solution.  Hand waves don't count.   I note that Kevin's answer appears to use "rexexp" (what SED had when I learned about it, unless it changed).

Comment: I also note that Kevins' answer principally finds port names in port names lists and renames them; then he suggests spitting out that list to cause renames in the body of the code.  Notice no mention of scoping.  I'd expect it to produce bad renames, too.  So his answer isn't evidence regexp is enough.  Now, if you don't care that it gets the answer wrong sometimes, this might be a perfectly good engineering solutions; you can patch the answer.  If you have a system of VHDL files containing a few million lines of code, this answer is NOT useful.   Chips these days are big and getting bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider  [program transformation tools (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).  The tools let you define a grammar/parser (and an unparser) that reads source text and builds ASTs; you can then define and apply source-to-source transformations to the code-as-ASTs.  When done, you use the unparser to regenerate valid source text.

Source to source transforms let you write patterns to recognize code of interest, and replace that code with modified code, all operating implicitly on the AST.

Comment: Ok guys thanks so far.

I'll give this a try and will have a look at all of the options.

Regards